# Yii2 mongodb Query class not found

Tags: mongodb, class, yii2

I am trying MongoDB integration with Yii2. I tried following the instructions at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
public function actionSearch($sku) {
    $query = new Query;
    // compose the query
    $query->select()
        ->from('products')
        ->where(['skus.sku' => $sku]);
    $product = $query->all();

    return $this->render('product', $product);
}
```

My use declarations are as follows:

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\mongodb\Query;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
```

The above results in:

```
Class 'yii\mongodb\Query' not found
```

Comment: Sorry for the question, but are you sure it has been installed ?

Comment: How did you install the yii2-mongodb extension? There are two approaches suggested in the README: via `composer.phar` or by adding to your `composer.json`. Have you also installed the prerequisite [MongoDB PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php)?

Comment: I did install the PHP extension, and also used composer.phar to install - didn't get any errors there, the files seem to be in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was reported to [yii2 issue tracker](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6958) and resolved there:

Application's `composer.json` (`basic/composer.json`) did not contain the `"yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "*"` line in the require section. Adding it and running `composer update` helped resolve the issue.